# Kubernetes/OpenShift: Can I patch a node condition status?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubectl, openshift-client-tools, kubernetes-go-client

I am trying to patch the node condition type status, for example can I turn/replace the Whatever Node Condition type status from false to true and vice versa?

Edit: When I try to patch I am not getting any errors by yet not being updated.

**Using Curl - I was able to update:**

```
curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json" -X PATCH APIserver:6443/api/v1/nodes/<node-name>/status --data '[{ "op": "replace", "path": "/status/conditions/-","value": { "type": "WhateverName", "status": "False" }}]'
```

Patch Example (not working):

```
oc patch node/<Node-Name> --type='json' -p '[{ "op": "replace", "path": "/status/conditions/0","value": { "type": "QuayState", "status": "True" }}]'
```

It's not giving errors but it's not changing anything, I am getting this output:

```
node/<nodeName> patched (no change)
```

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: Tried with even remove and it did not work:

oc patch node/<node-name> --type json --patch  '[{ "op": "remove", "path": "/status/conditions"}]'

Comment: I would not expect the node condition value to be something you can modify (e.g., it doesn't make any sense to change the `DiskPressure` condition, other than by freeing up disk space). Have you read something that leads you to expect otherwise?

Comment: @larsks
I am not talking about DiskPressure, I created my own node conditions and I want to patch them. I am using npd "Node Problem Detector" and I can create custom node conditions, trying to do curl, oc patch or with go lang client but no luck so far.

Comment: @larsks I got it actually running using curl but output as not expected, it adds new condition and not updating it.

curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json" -X PATCH https://APIserver:6443/api/v1/nodes/<node-name>/status --data '[{ "op": "replace", "path": "/status/conditions/-","value": { "type": "WhateverName", "status": "False" }}]'